# How to use dynamic color classes with Tailwind 3.3.3?

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css, tailwind-3, tailwind-in-js

In my project, I have used Tailwind 3.3.3 with Next JS 13.4.

As per project requirement, all the text color and background color i receive from the backend. So in my code I have used tailwind classes like this:

const classList = `text-[${blok?.text_color}] font-[${blok?.font_weight}]`;

As Tailwind removes classes which are not found in code so in my case all the classes were removed and i'm not able to see dynamic colors applied.

I have tried most of the solutions including **SafeList** in the configuration. But the issue is colors are not predefined, client can use any color.

I guess we can do the same with **inline styles** but I'm expecting solution with Tailwind which works for any color I receives from Back-end.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Hi Vishal, Do u know which colors will be come from the backend or how many colors will be come from the backend ? it means like get 1 color out of 10 colors. May I know solution for this.

Comment: No, Colors are not predefined. We will get any colors from back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue where I needed to set the color of components based on the setup from an API. I found this [useful tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/applying-dynamic-styles-tailwind-css/) that helped me a great deal.

Basically though, If you have RGB colors from the backend, then everything is pretty straight forward, you just need to use Javascript to update the css variables. Simply follow what you have in the [Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables) and use Javascript to update your css variable. Tailwind will pick whatever you have defined in the config.

However, if you are like me who needed to use hex color codes from the backend, you need to do some additional stuff, as the official docs didn't cover this.

**Steps**

1. In your tailwind.config.js color config, set your primary, secondary, etc colors as css variables. Example: `primary: withOpacity('--color-primary')`
2. Define your withOpacity function to handle Tailwind's opacity manipulation on your colors. This should be at the top of your tailwind.config.js.

   ```
   function withOpacity(variableName) {
     return ({ opacityVariable, opacityValue }) => {
       if (opacityValue !== undefined) {
         return `rgba(var(${variableName}), ${opacityValue})`
       }
       if (opacityVariable !== undefined) {
         return `rgba(var(${variableName}), var(${opacityVariable}, 1))`
       }
       return `rgb(var(${variableName}))`
     }
   }
   ```
3. In your app's Javascript, get your color values and set them as your css vars.

   Here's a snippet:

   Function to convert Hex to RGB:

   Credits: [Fbrill](https://github.com/fbrill/dynamic-colors-in-tailwind/blob/c0dddca3b9cbdbb0ba2d8ddf9583c56484362b04/utils/index.js#L21)

   ```
   function getRGBColor (hex) {
     if (!hex) return ''
     let color = hex.replace(/#/g, '')
     // if shorthand notation is passed in
     if (color.length !== 6) {
       color = `${color}${color}`
     }
     // rgb values
     const r = parseInt(color.substr(0, 2), 16)
     const g = parseInt(color.substr(2, 2), 16)
     const b = parseInt(color.substr(4, 2), 16)

     return `${r}, ${g}, ${b}`
   }
   ```

Function to set css variable:

```
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-primary', getRGBColor(YOUR_API_PRIMARY_COLOR_HEX_HERE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I had already tried this, but I forgot to mention that we are using Next Js 13.4 to leverage the benefits of server components. So window and document is not accessible on the server.

Thanks again for your solution.

Comment: Maybe you should do it inside your app layout component, with useEffect then?

You pass the color property as props from serverSideProps to the main layout component and you use useEffect to set the document style at top layer. Wanna try that?